# Android: ListView displays only last values saved in an array

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

hi i have tried the following code to store the user input values of EditText to an array in another activity and display the values in the array. every time the user input values in EditText of **Activity01**. it should be stored in an array on the **Activity02** to display all the values of user inputs. 
The ListView displays one last entered value from Array.
This is the code what i have tried.

**Activity01.java**

```
Button GrmBtnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grmbtnsave);       
Grmitem = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.itemsearch);   

GrmBtnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View view){            
Intent intent = new Intent ( ItemSearch.this, MainInvoiceActivity.class ); 
intent.putExtra("GRM_ITEM", Grmitem.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent); 
}
}
});
```

**Activity02.java**

```
ListView lv1;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//.....
//.....

lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.getalllist);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

String val="";
  if(getIntent().getStringExtra("GRM_ITEM")!=null && getIntent().getStringExtra("GRM_ITEM").length() > 0){
         val = getIntent().getStringExtra("GRM_ITEM");
         list.add(val);
    } 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I tried solving it but still i get the last entered value in the EditText.

Thank you for help

Comment: You need to consider sending array from activity1 to activity 2. Because android by default it will reset all the resources on OnDestroy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static keyword will do the magic.

Make change in declaration of list in your activity02.java like this. I have tested it. and it works.

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```